# query 2003 dhcp leases

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, perl, vbscript

Can I query my windows 2003 dhcp server from my windows xp in order to get the ip address if i have the mac address or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For a windows 2003 server query:**

```
netsh dhcp server <type.srvIP.here> scope s.s.s.s show client | find "clientIP"
netsh dhcp server <type.srvIP.here> scope s.s.s.s show client | find "MACAddress"
```

You'll need to know the scope (s.s.s.s) in which this client is on, to show scopes:

```
netsh dhcp server <type.srvIP.here> show scope
```

**Why not just query your network switch for it though?:**

```
arp -a "clientIP"
arp -a | find "MACAddress"
```

Comment: The command arp -a don't work because my network has many vlans seperated by routers. I want to search an ip address which is in an other vlans.
For the netsh command, i try to create a script to do this remotely from a desktop not directly on my dhcp servers.
On my xp i don't have the context dhcp in netsh.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Windows XP's netsh is a bit limited, unfortunately I don't know if it's possible to extend it (might be a good SF question.  At least for finding the MAC address of a windows host, you can use nbtstat -A "hostIP".

Comment: Thank you for the nbtstat command, it will help me a lot. The best would be to do the opposite, but I think it will be enough to make my script.